# Random sample from regex

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to test a tool on a small number of files from a directory. To run the tool on all files in the directory, I would run:

`./my-tool input/*.test`

However, the tool takes a long time to run and I would like to test it only on a subset of the files in `input/`. Currently, I am copying a random subset to another folder and using the regex to grab all files from that folder

My question is: Is there any way to limit the regex matches? i.e. a way to run  `./my-tool input/[PATTERN].test` Where `[PATTERN]` is a regex that will expand to only be `n` matches. Even better, is there a way to do that *and* randomize which ones are returned?

Comment: Are you asking how to limit the number of input files or the number of regex matches? Your question is not exactly clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On GNU/Linux you can easily and robustly select a subset of files with `shuf`:

```
shuf -ze -n 10 input/*.test | xargs -0 ./my-tool
```